# Vue memory leak when rendered components are removed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, vuex

Within a Vue application I am encountering a memory leak, the scenario in which it occurs is as follows:

- We have a component which is rendered within a v-for which contains many child components
- When the corresponding element is removed from the array the v-for rerenders these components and correctly removes the component that corresponds to the element removed from the array.

However the allocated memory is never freed, the application starts out with ~30-40 MB of RAM usage, which increases to 200MB RAM when the v-for is rendered (and eventually goes up to more than 1GB and crashes the browser when more elements are added or when switching). When the element is removed it stays steadily at 200MB (even when manually garbage collecting), so it seems like something it retaining my component.

I have tried locating the issue with heap snapshots but it only shows a child component as retainer. I cannot locate what is causing this component to not be garbage collected. I have tried unsubscribing all event listeners on the root with `this.$root.off` however this does not seem to help at all...

The code itself is condifential so I cannot just share it, however if a bit of code is necessary to understand the issue please let me know, so i can provide a replicated example.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this issue or has any ideas how to locate the cause of this memory leak?

**UPDATE**

This is the component which renders the components in the v-for:

```
<template>
    <b-tabs card class="tabMenu" v-model="index">
        <b-tab v-for="(tab) in tabs" @click="doSomething" @change="doSomething">
                <TabComponent :tab="tab"></TabComponent>
        </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
</template>

<script>
    import TabComponent from "./TabComponent";

    export default {
        components: {
            TabComponent,
        },
        created: function () {
            this.$root.$on("addTab", this.addTab);
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                tabs: this.$store.state.tabs,
            }
        },
        beforeDestroy: function(){             
            this.$root.$off("addTab");

        },
        methods: {
            addTab(tab) {
                this.$store.commit("addTab", {tab: tab});
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

And the tab component it renders:

```
<template>
    <div @mousedown.stop>
    <!--   Other components are loaded here but not relevant    -->
        <div>

                <div v-show="conditionA">
                    <resize-observer @notify="doSomething" v-if="conditionC"></resize-observer>

<!--          This component renders many SVG elements which can be found in the heapsnapshot as DetachedSvgElements when the parent is not present anymore          -->
                    <VisualizationComponent v-show="conditionD"
                                           :tab="tab"></VisualizationComponent>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {

            },
        props: {
            tab: TabObject,
        },
        data: function () {
            return {

            }
        },
        watch: {
           // Some watchers
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                // Do some calculations
                this.$root.$emit("updateSomething");
            });
        },
        created: function(){
            this.$root.$on("listen", this.doSomething);
            // And listen to more events
        },
        beforeDestroy: function(){
            this.$root.$off("listen");
            // And unsubscribe all others
        },
        computed: {
            // Quite a lot of computed props
        },
        methods: {
            // And also many methods for data processing
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Some kind of code example will for sure be required

Comment: I would suggest removing child components individually to see where the problem is.  Are any of these components:  1) Directly manipulating the DOM?  2) Creating objects in Vuex?  3) Working with large data sets?

Comment: @T.Short, added some code which resembles my actual code, I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: @Dan, yes some of these components store data in Vuex and the datasets are definitely big and a lot of processing is done on this data which is then visualized resulting in a large amount of components and DOM nodes (in the range of at least a few thousand up to half a million)

Comment: Try adding a key in the `v-for` to get better DOM rendering `<b-tab v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index" ...>` also when deleting the component try to delete the data from the store corresponding to it. Small tweaks sometimes help a lot :)

Comment: @HelderLucas, in the actual code the b-tab does contain a key, forgot to mention that. Also when we delete the component we delete in in Vuex and this is reflected back since tabs is directly linked to the state. So i know for sure it is removed from the store... That is the weird part for me....

Comment: Are you sure you're properly removing SVG elements from the DOM?  Does the problem persist if you remove the visualization component?

Comment: @Dan, when I comment out all SVG elements in the visualization component the leak still occurs (although it is obviously less of a leak since it renders almost nothing anymore at that point), as well as when i completely disable the visualization component

Comment: Take a look at Vue's official memory leak example [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) and verify that your app doesn't create this problem anywhere (looking at SVGs in particular, along with any other DOM manipulation).  You'll notice that memory leaks are typically a result of 3rd party DOM manipulation that hasn't been properly cleaned up.

Comment: @Dan, thank you for your response. We are not using any third party libraries for DOM manipulation and even excluding all svg elements does not prevent the leak (fyi we are using vuetify/bootstrap vue, could these cause an issue?)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Vuetify is a well tested library, I'd guess that's not the problem.  Another potential culprit is the `keep-alive`, which ensures that components are cached and not destroyed.  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @Dan, removing the keep alive sadly makes no difference....

Comment: Too bad, it may help to rebuild in a new project file by file until you figure it out.  (Please report back if you ever do figure it out)

Comment: Does you `<resize-observer>` element tear-down correctly? Could you create a repo as we currently are not able to try out solutions ourselves and this gets a guess-game...

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this? What did you do?

Comment: @DeliciousBacon yes, the solution of the accepted answer worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The object that I passed on through a property to the next component was complex and large in my case, I do not know if this is also the case for you?

My issue was solved by changing the way of passing my object. By changing the property to a number, in my case an ID, I was able to retrieve my object in the component where the property is used (based on the ID). As a result, I did not have to pass on the entire object repeatedly. For some reason passing large objects as data props is not working as it should and causes strange behavior...

In your case it maybe helps when you don't pass the 'tab' property directly to your component, but rather an index of the location of this element in the store and then fetching it directly from the store within your component.

So you need to change your v-for to:

```
<b-tab v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" @click="doSomething" @change="doSomething">
    <keep-alive>
        <TabComponent :tabIndex="index"></TabComponent>
    </keep-alive>
</b-tab>
```

And in your TabComponent:

```
props: {
    tabIndex: Number,
},
data: function () {
    return {
        tab: this.$store.state.tabs[this.tabIndex]
    }
}
```

Of course this principle would also need to be applied to any child components doing the same thing to prevent any memory leaks in child components which would obviously also impact the parents. Hopefully I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering vue to keep your components alive and asking why they are alive?!!!

Solution:
Just adding `max` prop to `<keep-alive>`  sudo-component and passing `tabs.length` value will force it to discard removed ones.

```
<keep-alive :max="tabs.length">
...
</keep-alive>
```

See [keep alive docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)

Comment: Thank you for your response, however if you take a look at the comments I have tried completely removing keep-alive which makes no differene ;)